# How to get variable value from specific node xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new here. How can i retrieve the value "blob" for my variable name: "FLOP" ?

Thanks in advance

XML :

```
<ROOT><XML><Oxo Txt="blob"></Oxo></XML></ROOT>
```

Formula :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="FLOP">
<xsl:value-of select="*//Oxo/@Txt"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

Actually i get nothing...

Answer (score 0):

#### Basics

It is not quite clear what you're trying to do.  XSL variables only *store* values.  Your current template only creates the variable and stores the value pointed to by the given XPath expression.

If you're trying to *output* your value, you need to add a line:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="FLOP">
        <xsl:value-of select="*//Oxo/@Txt"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- You need to output the value if you want to actually see it: -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$FLOP"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When I try the above template against your sample input XML, I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>blob
```

#### Refinements

You can clean up your XPath expression a bit.

```
*//Oxo/@Txt
```

This breaks down as follows:

```
*     ⇒ any input node
//Oxo ⇒ any "Oxo" descendant of that node
/@Txt ⇒ the "Txt" attribute of "Oxo"
```

Since this is in a template that only matches on the root element, the `*` matches that root.  The `//` part could be expensive, since it must evaluate **all** of the descendant nodes.  Since we're starting at the logical root, that means every element in the entire file.  Your sample XML is tiny, so we don't notice any real impact here -- but if your input file is large, things could really bog down.

If you already know the exact location of the `Oxo` element you want, just write that for the XPath:

```
/ROOT/XML/Oxo/@Txt
```

You can also tighten up your variable XSL.

```
    <xsl:variable name="FLOP">
        <xsl:value-of select="*//Oxo/@Txt"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
```

The `xsl:variable` element allows for its own `select` statement.  We can shorten this variable expression to a single line, plopping in our more-specific XPath while we're at it:

```
    <xsl:variable name="FLOP" select="/ROOT/XML/Oxo/@Txt"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Eirikr !